# how to compare string with sql  date in grails

Tags: grails

I have written query like this

```
Rule.findAll("FROM Rule WHERE client_id = ? " +
    "AND DATE_FORMAT(contract_begins,'%d-%m-%Y') <= ?", [tripStartDate])
```

But it is not able to compare the sql date with string `tripStartDate`, how to solve this problem ,how to check contract_begins is less than or equal to `tripStartDate`.

Comment: The trick is to let Hibernate do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to construct a new data object from your string to pass into the query. Assuming (I may be misunderstanding) contract_begins is mapped as a date type in your Rule

```
Date tripStart = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(tripStartDate)
Rule.findAllByClientAndContractBeginsLessThanEquals(client, tripStart)
```

or if you really want to keep the hql rather than dynamic finder

```
Date tripStart = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(tripStartDate)
Rule.findAll("FROM Rule WHERE client_id = :clientId AND contract_begins <= :tripStart",
        [clientId: client.id, tripStart: tripStart])
```